# Move scroll to top with the selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a `ul` of multiple elements, I would like to scroll the bar to see the selected item always on the top. This item will have assigned the `selected` class. Up to now, I have managed to scroll the bar to the position of this element but not to scroll it to the top of the container.

My code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery('li.selected').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please post the minimum required code to reproduce the issue. Add your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse to the `parent` element like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var x = jQuery('li.selected').parent();
    jQuery('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(x).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

I used this in a similar situation: It was not possible to traverse directly in the `scrollTop`... line, so I used a variable to select the parent and put this variable into the `scrollTop` line.

Comment: The solution worked fine for me. I had to make a couple of changes to calibrate the top position of the element but otherwise perfect. Thank you so much.